# Android Studio parsing RRS

Tags: java, android, json, xml

there is such an RRS tape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <rss version="2.0">

        <item>
            <title>Sale 500 point</title>
            <discount>500 p.</discount>
            <description><![CDATA[
                <p><a href="http://www.link.com/1_1"><img src="http://www.link.com/1_1.jpg" width="143" height="59" /></a></p>
                <p><b>New acc sale 500 point<a href="http://www.link.com/1_2">Try IT</a></b></p>
                <br />
                <p><b>Your Key: </b>IDKSA0</p>
                <p><b>More: </b>TEXTEXTEXTEXTEXTEX</p>
                <br />
                <p><b>dTime: </b> 03.11.2017 22:04 <b> 13.11.2017 23:59</b></p>]]></description>
        </item>
```

I can pull out:
[Sale 500 point]
[500 p.]

```
for( Element item : doc.select("item") )
        {
            catalog[0][i]=item.select("title").first().text();
            catalog[1][i]=item.select("discount").first().text(); 
i++;
        }
```

how can I get this ANY information:

- http://www.link.com/1_1
- http://www.link.com/1_1.jpg
- New acc sale 500 point
- http://www.link.com/1_2
- Try IT
- Your Key:
- IDKSA0
- More:
- TEXTEXTEXTEXTEXTEX
- 13.11.2017 23:59

how can I convert the query:
item.select("description").first().text();
To separately value from under the tag "description".
sry eng. Need any info.thk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using ROME for parsing RSS.
ROME is a Java framework for RSS and Atom feeds. It's open source and licensed under the Apache 2.0 license.

Comment: It? 
 https://rometools.github.io/rome/HowRomeWorks/RomeV0.4TutorialUsingRomeToCreateAndWriteASyndicationFeed.html